# Vue.js putting the same value in two different slots

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have the following template in Vue.js

```
<template>
    <span>
        <span class="format-decimal">{{toHoursDecimal(minutes)}}<slot></slot></span>
        <span class="format-minutes">{{toHoursMinutes(minutes)}}<slot></slot></span>
    </span>
</template>
```

This in turn gets used in the following way in my web page:

```
<k-duration :minutes="scheduleData.totalBreaksInMinutes"><br></k-duration>
<k-duration :minutes="scheduleData.pause"></k-duration>
```

The thing is that I get a warning that says you cannot have multiple default slots in the same working tree. Of course, this is because I have the two slots and Vue.js doesn't like it.

Now, I tried various ways with one single slot, but the thing is that what goes there is a line break... and if I even think of putting the line break anywhere but where it currently is, the line below gets misaligned by a couple of pixels.

Also, the two `<span>` inside the template are never displayed at the same time. They're toggles between two different display settings. Basically, all I want is to get rid of the warning.

I've read a lot of things on scoped slots, named slots... but basically, all I really want is the same value put in those two places at once. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: I don't think slots are intended to be used this way. If the `<slot></slot>` is either always a line break, or empty, then you could replace it with `<br v-if="includeLineBreak">`, where `includeLineBreak` is a prop on the component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [named slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Named-Slots):

```
<template>
    <span>
        <span class="format-decimal">{{toHoursDecimal(minutes)}}<slot></slot></span>
        <span class="format-minutes">{{toHoursMinutes(minutes)}}<slot name="two"></slot></span>
    </span>
</template>
```

The first slot will be the default one and the second one can be used by explicitly setting the name:

```
<k-duration :minutes="scheduleData.totalBreaksInMinutes">This will go into the default slot<br></k-duration>
<k-duration :minutes="scheduleData.pause"><span slot="two">This will go into the second slot</span></k-duration>
```

As a side note, if all you're doing is putting a line-break, you better off just using css.